# Python BeautifulSoup Access Div container

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to grab the container from below product detail page that contains brand, product name, price etc.

According to chrome site-inspection it is a "**div**" container from the class "**product-detail__info**" (please see screenshot)

Unfortunately my code does work...

I would appreciate if someone could give me a tip :)

Thanks in advance

Link: https://www.nemlig.com/opvasketabs-all-in-one-5039333

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = "https://www.nemlig.com/opvasketabs-all-in-one-5039333"

#Opening connection and grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()

#Closing connection
uClient.close()

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#grabs product detail container
container = page_soup.find_all("div", {"class": "product-detail__info"})



print(container)
```

[image]

Comment: page is dynamic. Either grab the data from the request made to get that info, or use Selenium to render the page first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data that you are looking for is part of the source page (as a script).
Here is the code that will return it to you:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import json

r = requests.get('https://www.nemlig.com/opvasketabs-all-in-one-5039333')
if r.status_code == 200:
    soup = soup(r.text, "html.parser")
    scripts = soup.find_all("script")
    data = json.loads(scripts[6].next.strip()[:-1])
    print(data)
```

output

```
[{'@context': 'http://schema.org/', '@type': 'Organization', 'url': 'https://www.nemlig.com/', 'logo': 'https://www.nemlig.com/https://live.nemligstatic.com/s/b1.0.7272.30289/scom/dist/images/logos/nemlig-web-logo_tagline_rgb.svg', 'contactPoint': [{'@type': 'ContactPoint', 'telephone': '+45 70 33 72 33', 'contactType': 'customer service'}], 'sameAs': ['https://www.facebook.com/nemligcom/', 'https://www.instagram.com/nemligcom/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/nemlig-com']}, {'@context': 'http://schema.org/', '@type': 'Product', 'name': 'Opvasketabs all in one', 'brand': 'Ecover', 'image': 'https://live.nemligstatic.com/scommerce/images/opvasketabs-all-in-one.jpg?i=ZowWdq-y/5039333', 'description': '25 stk. / zero / Ecover', 'category': 'Maskinopvask', 'url': 'https://www.nemlig.com/opvasketabs-all-in-one-5039333', 'offers': {'@type': 'Offer', 'priceCurrency': 'DKK', 'price': '44.95'}}]
```